# webservice response received but not bound to event.result

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, flex4

I get the webservice(spring WebService) response properly ,but the event.result object is null.I can see the SOAP response body in the event.message.body variable.

### ## Soap Response ##

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><getUserUserTasksResponse xmlns="http://ws.burr.com/BurWS/9_0">
<foundTasks>
<taskList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Task">
<description>Task1</description>
<estartDate>2011-03-29</estartDate>
<astartDate>2011-03-29</astartDate><
efinishDate>2011-03-29</efinishDate>
<afinishDate>2011-03-29</afinishDate>
<status>Start</status><
</taskList>
</getUserUserTasksResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you're using resultFormat="object" and the server is returning a non-valid response. Try setting resultFormat="e4x", and if the result comes through, that's the problem.

Use something like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to validate server response XML, as Spring has no problems sending out invalid responses, which causes all sorts of problems for Flex.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It was actually a problem with the wsdl definition in spring for the response object.